# move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move

Tags: php

```php
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "/profile/img/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$location = "img/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];

mysql_query("update  users set user_img = '$location' WHERE user_email = '$_SESSION[user]' ")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Make sure you have permission on the folder you want to move the file(s) into.

Comment: whats the *exact* error message?

Comment: Warning: move_uploaded_file(/profile/img/P_20160913_122227_BF.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp1\htdocs\myweb\profile\student_avatar.php on line 40

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp1\tmp\php4773.tmp' to '/profile/img/P_20160913_122227_BF.jpg' in C:\xampp1\htdocs\myweb\profile\student_avatar.php on line 40

Comment: Try with absolute path. like http://domain/profile/img/image.jpg

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.
I flagged this question for closing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use document_root to get absolute path like this:

```
$target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/profile/img/" . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes very often to all and these are the necessary checks that has to be made before you do file uploading and such activities.

### Instructions - General Checks

1. Ensure that you have the form attribute called `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.
2. Ensure that you have the `name` for the file type. `<input type="file" name="image" />`.
3. Ensure that you get the file uploaded in the PHP Script like `$_FILES['image']['name']`.
4. Make sure you have the changing the upload folder `chmod 755` or `777` like `chmod 777 folder_path`.

And after all the necessary check you can add the following code for the file upload.

```
$target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."YOUR_NEEDED_PATH_TO_MOVE".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_path);
```

Hope so all these instructions helps for all the developers including you.

Happy Coding:)